# Pass data to transclusion scope in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to pass data to transclude scope to make variable existing only in there. I mean I'm creating component:

```
.component('testComp', { 
    bind: { 
        collection: '<'
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'testcomptemplate.html',
    controller: TestCompController
});
```

With template:

```
<div>
    <ng-transclude ng-repeat="$item in $ctrl.collection"></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

And while using that component in another file I want to make `$item` variable available in it's transclude:

```
<div>
    <test-comp collection="someCollection">
        {{ $item.name }}
    </test-comp>
</div>
```

I've already tried making another component which would be transclude either or directive but still can't make it done. Anything what I could name progress was accessing to `$item` through `$parent` variable.
Is this even possible in component?

Comment: @ThaFor, I need few inputs from you. $item is a parent component in the current component class

Comment: That's not the way the `ng-transclude` directive works. Transcluded template inherits from parent scope, not component scope.

Comment: I know and that's the point if something like this is possible